How do i add any video as my background of a section with decreased opacity in html bootstrap?
`Hello there! I am first time coding my own website and i have successfully created a website to make it more attractive i want to make some section background as a video background which auto adjust its size according to device.
Here is my code where i wanna add stuff : `
<section id="about" class="test-gradient-background about-section whiteline">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h2>Who are we?</h2>
          <p>Paragraph </p>
          <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-primary btn-lg">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
        <video id="videobcg" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0">
          <source src="./images/chess.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         </video>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
          <img src="./images/C8N.png" class="img-fluid cropped-ofp" alt="C8N Image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

css : 

.gradient-background {
  background: linear-gradient(300deg, #00bfff, #ff4c68, #ef8172);
  background-size: 180% 180%;
  animation: gradient-animation 18s ease infinite;
}


.whiteline {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

`can some tell how do i integrate a video tag that perfectly fine and adjust itself i tried a lot but wasted many hours on this.
I watch serveral youtube videos for adding video background but it doesnt work like it work for them. I want to integrate some lines of code that can add video background or by changing line of code that have same functionality.`

this is the perfect CSS for me...
  video {
      object-fit: cover;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

the secret is in the parameters vidth an height, units are viewport width like 100% an viewport height 100% with vw and vh.
